# Как перейти на другой сайт?

Tags: php

С сайта example.com я хочу перейти на example1.com (php). Как?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php header('Location: https://www.example.com/'); exit; ?>
```

→ Всё о PHP находитка [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/) , изучайте!